# Name can't be changed more than once every 30 days bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names

I tried to change my Meta Stack Overflow username today, and it said I have to wait 30 days between changing names:

> Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on Apr 7 at 1:19

I have never changed my username, obviously - what's going on?

---

Oh yeah, and I tried to change it to "minitech η". This is my new username for reference even if I can't currently change it.

Comment: Strange.  I'm seeing a profile sync on March 8, which apparently counts as a display name change.  `Mar 8 edit displayname from minitech to minitech; via profile sync`

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I thought that might be it - just a description update, but it was the first time I tried "Copy to all Stack Exchange accounts". Oh well :(

Comment: +1 I've seen this before after erroneously applying my profile updates without updating my username.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Profile syncs don't count as name changes, unless this has changed recently. And profile syncs from `minitech` to `minitech`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting in the next build, pushing profiles between sites will only count as a name change (for name change throttling purposes) if a user's display name actually changes.

It will also go through and remove the (most recent) bogus history records preventing name changes that were caused by this bug.